# Jquery retrieving element without certain class

Tags: jquery

I have two divs.

```
<div  dpath="somepath"  class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
<div  dpath="anotherpath"  class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
```

I want to get the div object  without the class 'ui-tabs-hide'. I have tried :

```
var tab = $('.ui-tabs-panel').not('.ui-tabs-hide');
```

This is not working.

Comment: That should work though. Does the element already have all the classes when you are trying to select it? The jQuery plugin might be initialized *after* you try to select those elements.

Comment: mhhh, that should work. Could you add more code?

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mN9Va/

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/Wn7p2/

Comment: Could you please post more of your html?

Comment: Okay thanks guys, narrows the problem down.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, just your html is invalid, you have to close div tags:

http://jsfiddle.net/mGSsG/

```
<div dpath="somepath" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"></div>
<div dpath="anotherpath" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
```

Comment: I assume this is only part of the HTML. It wouldn't make sense to have tabs without content anyways, would it? This is more of a comment than an answer IMO (if there is no problem anyway, the question should be closed).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, see below link:

```
<div  dpath="somepath"  class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">AAAAAAAAA</div>
<div  dpath="anotherpath"  class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">BBBBBBBBB</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sBWSq/